# Pylon gst-plugin-vision for Gstreamer by joshDoe

Tags: python-3.x, gstreamer

I have installed the plugin from github/joshdoe/gst-plugins-vision and using the Pylon gst.
I get error when I try to use the gstreamer plugin in python.
Any ideas? I have asked the question in github forum too, but since its more python related I figured I get a better chance of answer here.

CODE:

```
import cv2
import sys
import gi
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst


def open_cam(width, height):
    # We want to set width and height here, otherwise we could just do:
    #     return cv2.VideoCapture(dev)
    gst_str = ('pylonsrc config-file=acA2040.pfs! '            
               'queue ! '
               'videoconvert ! appsink').format(width, height)
    return cv2.VideoCapture(gst_str, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

def main():
    print(cv2.__version__)
    gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
    Gst.debug_set_active(True)

    Gst.debug_set_default_threshold(3)
    cap = open_cam(2048, 2048)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        sys.exit("Failed to open camera!")
    Gst.init(None)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

ERROR:

---

```
sudo python3 main.py
main.py:4: PyGIWarning: Gst was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gst
4.2.0
0:00:00.441833101 18495      0x2d48440              pylonsrc gstpylonsrc.c:3675:gst_pylonsrc_load_configuration:<pylonsrc0> PylonC error: PylonC error #c2000001 'Could not load features from file.' (0xc2000001).

0:00:00.441950413 18495      0x2d48440              pylonsrc gstpylonsrc.c:3675:gst_pylonsrc_load_configuration:<pylonsrc0> PylonC error: Function 'PylonFeaturePersistenceLoad' failed in source file '../../../../../../../Pylon/PylonC/PylonC/PylonC.cpp' line #5187
Caused by an exception thrown from source file '../../../../../../Pylon/PylonUtility/FeaturePersistence.cpp' line #503.
The file could not opened for reading.

0:00:00.444235795 18495      0x2d48440 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3468:gst_base_src_start:<pylonsrc0> error: Failed to start
0:00:00.444327001 18495      0x2d48440 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3824:gst_base_src_activate_push:<pylonsrc0> Failed to start in push mode
0:00:00.444374673 18495      0x2d48440 WARN                GST_PADS gstpad.c:1142:gst_pad_set_active:<pylonsrc0:src> Failed to activate pad
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1758) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module pylonsrc0 reported: GStreamer error: state change failed and some element failed to post a proper error message with the reason for the failure.
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (888) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
Failed to open camera!
```

Comment: It looks like you have a wrong configuration file `acA2040.pfs`